# mysql: Count number of users accessing resourse for specific time based on 1 hour interval

Tags: mysql, intervals, hour, accounting

I have a table - containing user active at the time of check (date_time) and name of the user accessing resource. I want to count the users using the system, assuming that the user is accountable only if he had access for more than 5 minutes.

```
date_time           user_access
2017-06-24 09:01:59 mike
2017-06-24 09:04:13 mike
2017-06-24 09:07:13 mike
2017-06-24 09:11:14 joe
2017-06-24 09:18:17 ron
2017-06-24 09:24:10 rick
2017-06-24 09:25:24 ron
2017-06-24 09:39:16 ron
2017-06-24 09:44:07 ron
2017-06-24 09:51:44 mary
2017-06-24 09:54:27 joe
2017-06-24 09:58:55 joe
```

I expect the result to be

```
date_time interval   user_count
2017-06-24 09:00     3
2017-06-24 10:00     0
```

(Counting only Mike, Ron and Joe -  because they were logged for more than 5 minutes and not counting Rick and Mary, because they were logged only once).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need  the count of user i  the last hour

```
 select date(date_time), HOUR(date_time), count(distinct user)
 FROM  my_table 
 date_time >= date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour)
 group by date(date_time), HOUR(date_time)
```

and this should be select the result for the user logged  for more that 5 minutes

```
    select date(date_time), HOUR(date_time), count(distinct user)
    FROM  my_table 
    date_time >= date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour)
    group by date(date_time), HOUR(date_time)
    and user_access in (  
      select user_access  
      from my_table
      where timediff(max(date_time), min(date_time))/60 > 5
      group by user_access
    )
```

Comment: Thanks!
It is OK for the part of the question. I need some way to count the users which was logged at least 5 minutes. Any ideas?

Comment: answer udpdate with the  5 minutes users